# Object as a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to have following working, so object returned by getObject function will be up to date. I assume it could be done if object is in fact a function or may be there could be other ways to do it.

```
var o;
var module = {
  setObject: function(newObject) {
    o = newObject;
  },
  getObject: function() {
    if(o) {
      return o;
    }
    o = {"a": "123"}
    return o
  }
}
var objCopy = module.getObject();
console.log(objCopy.a)
module.setObject({"a":"321"})
console.log(objCopy.a)
```

As seen setting new object doesn't change `objCopy` apparently and output would be "123", "123".
What could be ways to achieve this?
Basically object creator module is Node.js module used by other code.

Comment: You have to reassign `objCopy` with `getObject()` for this code to work as you want it to. As in you have to do `var objCopy = module.getObject();` after you call `setObject`. Otherwise `objCopy` will be a reference to the old object.

Comment: Consider prototypical inheritance and binding internal object properties with `this`

Comment: Why are you using a global variable, seems to defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Make o a property of module, or another object.

```
var o = { obj: undefined };
var module = {  
    setObject: function(newObject) {
        o.obj = newObject;
    },
    getObject: function() {
        if(o) {
          return o;
        }
        o.obj = {"a": "123"}
        return o
    }
}
var objCopy = module.getObject();
console.log(objCopy.obj.a)
module.setObject({"a":"321"})
console.log(objCopy.obj.a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
    var o;
    var module = {
      o:{"a":"123"},
      setObject: function(newObject) {
        this.o = newObject;
      },
      getObject: function() {
        return this.o;
      }
    }
    var objCopy = module;
    console.log(objCopy.getObject())
    module.setObject({"a":"321"})
    console.log(objCopy.getObject())
```

Answer (score 0):

Mmm I don't understand why are you creating that, can you explain why? That's isn't following the concept of OOP

What's happening is that "return o" is returning the value of "o", and you're losing the reference. Then, setObject is just changing the value of "o", which is global

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
var module = {
  o: {},
  setObject: function(newObject) {
    this.o = newObject;
  },
  getObject: function(objName) {
    return this[objName];
  }
}
module.setObject({"a": "123"})
var objCopy = module;
module.setObject({"a":"321"});
console.log(objCopy.getObject("o"));
console.log(module.getObject("o"));
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMQqLa